# SDK de coinAPI con python: ¿Cómo saber que argumento tengo que pasarle al script?

Tags: python, api

Mi objetivo es consumir la API de CoinApi. Para ello utilizo su SDK en pyhon.
Un ejemplo de código podría ser este:

```
from coinapi_rest_v1 import CoinAPIv1
import datetime, sys

test_key = sys.argv[1]

api = CoinAPIv1(test_key)
exchanges = api.metadata_list_exchanges()

print('Exchanges')
for exchange in exchanges:
    print('Exchange ID: %s' % exchange['exchange_id'])
    print('Exchange website: %s' % exchange['website'])
    print('Exchange name: %s' % exchange['name'])
```

En vez de obtener una lista de exchanges de criptomonedas, me da lugar el siguiente error:

```
file "RUTAALDIRECTORIODELPROYECTO/examples.py", line 4, in <module>
    test_key = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Deduzco que argv es un array pero no sé ni donde está (parece que está en sys pero no sé donde está sys) ni que se supone que debe contener.
Me pregunto que es sys.
Así que escribo el siguiente código:

```
from coinapi_rest_v1 import CoinAPIv1
import datetime, sys

print(sys)
```

Y la consola me dice `<module 'sys' (built-in)>`
La verdad es que me gustariá meterme en el fichero sys.py a ver si encuentro un array llamado argv y deduzco para que sirve...

Encontré este artículo en inglés [sys.argv[1], IndexError: list index out of range [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689100/sys-argv1-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range#:%7E:text=argv%20is%20the%20list%20of,length%201%20and%20so%20sys.), según este artículo parece que le tengo que pasar un argumento al script de python, pero no sé que argumento le tengo que pasar, supongo que será uno relacionado con la API. He mirado [la documentación de la API](https://docs.coinapi.io/#md-rest-api), pero no hace referencia a Python solo te describe las diferentes peticiones http y como son las respuestas.
**Lo que quiero es consumir la API ¿Cómo puedo saber que argumento le tengo que pasar al script en python?**

Comment: No encontré la documentación pero en el código fuente estan los métodos que permite la SDK de Python [CoinAPIv1](https://github.com/coinapi/coinapi-sdk/blob/master/data-api/python-rest/coinapi_rest_v1/coinapi_rest_v1.py#L178). Esa test_key debe ser una llave de la API que genera CoinApi para que puedas autenticarte, en el [plan gratuito](https://www.coinapi.io/pricing?apikey) te la envian por mail, no se en los demas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero que antes de intentar hacer algo complicado, como mínimo completes el [tutorial oficial de Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). Ahí está explicado qué es [sys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) (un módulo estándar) y qué es [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) (la lista de argumentos con que fue invocado tu programa). Es algo básico que pertenece al lenguaje, no tiene nada que ver con CoinAPI, por eso no lo vas a encontrar en la documentación de esa API sino en la documentación de la librería estándar de Python.

Por ejemplo, si ejecutas tu script de esta forma:

```
python mi_script.py cualquier cosa
```

dentro de mi_script.py vas a encontrar que `sys.argv[1]=='cualquier'` y `sys.argv[2]=='cosa'` (y `sys.argv[0]=='mi_script.py'`)

Comment: Muchas gracias!